# Query params with special characters in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request.querystring

My URL:

```
http://abcde.com/result.aspx?q=(some%20name%20here%20):Done&p=1&pos=0&qType=2
```

Its working in postman and also in curl command. If i try this in nodejs code

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "abcde.com",
  "port": null,
  "path": "/result.aspx?q=(some%2520name%2520here%2520)%3ADone&p=1&pos=0&qType=2",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "8e755cba-5d19-446f-269e-e880bd8cd7e1"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

Its not working. I think, problem is some special characters in query params. can anyone know how to fix this issue.

Comment: When I tried the above code against https://httpbin.org/get, it seems to work fine. What do you mean when you say that "it's not working"? This is what I get - https://paste.ubuntu.com/23378430/. It could have to do with the fact that the original URL is double-encoded in your Node request.

Comment: @Shade Hope you got my point. Why this issue araise. due to query params or something else?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't get your point. What doesn't work?

Comment: Can you please try this sample link http://lawfinderlive.com/Results.aspx?q=(SUPREME%20AND%20COURT%20AND%20OF%20AND%20INDIA):Court&p=1&qType=2 i got this from net. this same problem i am facing in my project also